# How to retrieve date of birth of all connections in linkedIn API?

Tags: linkedin-api

I want to get the date of birth of connections using LinkedIn api.I got some informations using

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:(headline,first-name,last-name,location)
```

If i am trying to add `dateOfBirth` or `date-of-birth` parameter to this api but it is not working. Can anyone please help me to get the date of birth of all connections?

Comment: Did you obtain `r_fullprofile` permission?

Comment: The parameter is `date-of-birth`: http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields

Comment: date-of-birth parameter will work for logged in user account not for connection's date of birth.

Comment: ya i added "r_fullprofile" permission. its giving all details but not date of birth.

Comment: does the user have date of birth filled in ?

Comment: ya bro. if u will request DOB of logged in account you can get.

Answer (score 0):

headline,first-name,last-name,location are comes under basic profile but date-of-birth comes under full profile. So you have add the permission(**r_fullprofile**) for this one. Try Like this

```
NSArray *grantedAccess = @[@"r_basicprofile ",@"r_fullprofile", @"r_network"];
```

Comment: No bro. its retrieving all connection's profile informations but not date of birth.

Answer (score -1):

[According to this document](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields#profile), you will need to apply to be able to retrieve the full profile information, like date of birth:

> **Member profile fields available to Apply with LinkedIn developers**
>
> The following selection of profile fields are only available to applications that have applied and been approved for the Apply with LinkedIn program:
>
> - Full Profile Fields
> - (...)

For more information, visit the [**Apply with Linkedin**](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/apply-with-linkedin) page.

**Note:** This is an old question but things may have changed, so this is for future reference.